# SharedPreferences.getInt("cumulative", 0) catch 22 - how to resolve?

Tags: android, android-preferences

Unlike other values, in which I can initialize in `onCreate()` every time the app starts:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("re-initiative-value", 0);
    editor.commit();
  }
```

a cumulative value stored in SharedPreferences poses a problem for me (I can't really re-initialize it every time the program starts).

As a result, whenever I attempt `prefs.getInt("cumulative-valuee", 0)`,  I get a RuntimeException:

```
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1234, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.app/com.example.app.MyActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3515)
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3557)
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2063)
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(ContextImpl.java:2707)
```

What is a good strategy to avoid this type of exception?

I was thinking of placing the call to getInt() within a try-catch clause, so that I can write it in the first ever program start, but then I realized: Isn't the default value in getInt() (the 2nd parameter) meant exactly for such case?

UPDATE: Trying to verify @MyBD's suggestion, I added the following code to dump all preferences names and values upon first run:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

Map<String,?> allPrefs = prefs.getAll();
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allPrefs.entrySet())
  Log.i("allPrefs", entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
```

The resulting log shows no type mismatch.

This must be a different problem masquerading as `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I "solved" the problem, by placing the following code in `onCreate()`:

```
try {
  int dummy = prefs.getInt("cumulative-valuee", 0) + 1 ; // <== this generate exception -- why?
  Log.i("dummy ready", " ==> " + dummy);
}
catch (ClassCastException e) {
  Editor editor = prefs.edit();
  editor.putInt("cumulative-valuee", 0);  
  editor.commit();

  int dummy = prefs.getInt("cumulative-valuee", 0) + 1 ; // <== try again (should yield NO exception)
  Log.i("dummy ready", " ==> " + dummy);
}
```

It works. :)

Answer (score 4):

From your exception it seems like you do have this name for a string preference, not that this preference doesn't exists:

```
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
05-12 16:45:50.489: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1767):     at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(ContextImpl.java:2707)
```

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> Returns the preference value if it
>   exists, or defValue. Throws
>   ClassCastException if there is a
>   preference with this name that is not
>   an int.

If you change its name, it should work.

Comment: Thanks++. It is possible that somewhere during the development of my app, that preference was defined as String, but the problem started only after I uninstalled the app, then re-installed it. Aren't app's preferences deleted too when the app is uninstalled?

Comment: @Tim Thanks and +1 for confirming this.

Comment: I changed the name. It still throws this exception. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Found this, it occurs whenever you have an existing pref which is a different class than you are requesting.

So for instance if you've stored a String, but use Prefs.getInt(); this will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your prefs object properly? This does not appear in the code you've provided.

Comment: Yes I did. the prefs object works for all other preferences except for this one.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem. It was solved when I assigned keys for all preferences. So, check yor prefrerences.xml for empty keys)